# Generate Auth token using API + client certificate with password using playwright tool

Tags: api, playwright, auth-token

In this we are Sending HTTP request with parameter as client certificate and password to get the Auth Token from server. we are doing this with playwright tool in typescript lang.

**Getting Error like- 400 Bad Requests**

```
import { test, expect } from "@playwright/test"; import { stringify } from 'querystring'; 
test('test', async ({ request, baseURL }) => {

const response = await request.post("https://abc.unobank.com/syst-open-banking//private/oauth2/token", { 

headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',     
},
    data:stringify ({
        grant_type: 'client_credentials',
        scope: 'accounts payments funds confirmations',
        client_id: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        username : 'xxxxxxxx_path_of _client_certificate_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        password: 'xxxxxxxxx_certificate_password_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    })
    });
console.log(response);
});
```